# Solving linear program with 1 quadratic constraint complexity

Tags: np-hardness, optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following linear program,

$$\min y \\
xc_1 \leq c_2 + yz,\\
x = x_1 + \dots + x_n,\\
z \leq x_1 + x_2, \\
z \leq x_2 + x_3, \\
\vdots\\
z \leq x_{n-1} + x_n, \\
x,x_1, \dots, x_n,y,z \geq 0
$$ 
where $c_1, c_2$ are constants. This is an example of quadratically constrained linear program where I have 1 quadratic constraint. I wish to find out if this problem is NP-Hard or not. The quadratic constraint can be expressed in the form $\vec{y}M\vec{y}^T$ where $M$ for my problem is not positive semidefinite (and thus, non-convex) which is perhaps evidence of hardness

Listing specific questions below:

1. Can this problem be transformed into a linear program by taking logarithms?
2. Is there any literature reference or reduction showing that linear programs with non-convex quadratic constraints is an NP-Hard problem?

Edit : Cross posted question at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433177/solving-linear-program-with-1-quadratic-constraint-complexity/2433348#2433348)

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2433177/14578, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/39108/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.   Our site policy prohibits simultaneous cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

Based on posts from [or-exchange](http://or-exchange.com) and some internet reading, the following algorithm works. We adapt the cutting plane method to binary search for variable $y$. For my problem, the upper and lower bounds for all variables are known (but if these are not known, one can find a bound on $y$ by solving the LP by removing the first constraint). Let $l \leq y \leq u$.

Fix $y = (l+u)/2$. This converts the program to a linear program. If the resulting constraints are feasible, update $u(l) = (l+u)/2$. Keep performing the binary search until we reach the optimal solution with an additive $\epsilon_0$. The running time of the algorithm is $O(PTIME)\log\frac{u-l}{\epsilon_0}$.

While this algorithm can find the optimal solution within a small additive constant, I am still not sure about the hardness of the problem for solving exactly. Any comments regarding complexity are welcome!

Comment: As I said in the answer on math.stackechange, you can solve it analytically (empirically you will see that every second $x_i$ will be zero and all other elements equal to the same value, call it $\mu$, hence $z$ will be equal to $\mu$ at optimality, plug into first constraint and minimize left-hand side analytically). All you have to do is to prove that this solution actually is the optimal choice

Comment: but unfortunately, you will see that the problem does not have any minimizer, as the optimal cost tends to $c_1\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ for $\mu \rightarrow \infty$